# TWIG dataUrl function for resized images

Tags: templating, image-transforms, emails, function

Craft provides the very nice TWIG function `dataUrl(pathToImg)` to inline images in e-mails.

E.g.

```
<img src="{{ dataUrl('@webroot/assets/img/logo.svg')" />
```

will base64 encode the image into the `src`. This also works if you pass in an instance of an asset:

```
{% set myAsset = craft.assets.id(123).one() %}
<img src="{{ dataUrl(myAsset) }}" />
```

My question: Does anyone know how to resize the image first, if you pass in an asset?

This does not work:

```
<img src="{{ dataUrl(myAsset.getUrl({width: 200, height: 200})) }}" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, this works:

```
<img src="{{ dataUrl('@webroot' ~ myAsset.getUrl({width: 200, height: 200}, true)) }}" />
```

Two important things:

- prepend the `@webroot` alias to the `myAsset.getUrl(...)`
- set the second parameter of `getUrl(...)` to `true`: `myAsset.getUrl({...}, true)`. This ensures that a real file path is returned by `getUrl`, because the image is transformed immediately on call. This is necessary for the `dataUrl` function to work. If it is not present, Craft might return a URL pointing to the image transformation controller (which transforms when called for the first time, this might go wrong here).

Comment: It seems this only works with locally-stored images. I'm trying to get it working with remote images on DigitalOcean Spaces, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

One method that comes to my mind is to create an asset configuration in admin panel (Settings -> Assets), where you can create different Image Transform configurations.

For example, I can create an Image Transforms called *Thumbnail* then set the required dimensions and quality of the image.

Once you create an Image Transforms, you can utilize them with twig template:

```html
myAsset.getUrl('thumbnail')
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question was how to get a resized image into dataUrl(...)

Comment: @MatthiasRedl-Mann My apologies - I think I've misunderstood the question

Comment: No worries, good that you tried!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Asset::setTransform](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-asset.html#method-settransform) or [Asset::copyWithTransform](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-asset.html#method-copywithtransform) to get (a copy) of the asset object with your transform applied. Then you can pass that into dataUrl().

```
{# Apply the transform to myAsset directly #}
{% do myAsset.setTransform({width: 200, height: 200}) %}
{{ dataUrl(myAsset)  }}

{# Use this if you need myAsset without the transform later #}
{% set thumb = myAsset.copyWithTransform({width: 200, height: 200}) %}
{{ dataUrl(thumb)  }}
```

Comment: how would I call the static methods from TWIG?

Comment: @Matthias Redl-Mann Sorry for the confusion, they're not static methods, that's just a code notation convention. You can call the methods like any other instance method using dot-notation. I updated the code example with working examples for both methods, either of them should work correctly now.

Comment: Looks good, I will try!

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible to get a dataUrl from a resized asset at this time, not even in Craft 4.

There’s already an issue for that: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/discussions/11388.

In an older, closed issue, the reason is explained: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/10108.

It is said to be possible with the [Imager X plugin.](https://plugins.craftcms.com/imager-x) And there is a dedicated [Blur Hash Plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/blur-hash).

Comment: It is possible, see solution above

Comment: Are you sure the transformation is used? I tried your solution and I got huge base64 code that obviously was generated from the original image file. Brandonkelly explained in November 2021: «dataUrl() doesn’t support image transforms, and we can’t fix that because the transformed image might not be readily available.» The discussion he asked to open is still open.

Comment: 1.) Did you use the true as second argument to getUrl?

Comment: 2.) This is important, since otherwise Brandon is right

Comment: 3.) I even tried it again for you and took a screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/rD2lHd4poo7x.png

Comment: And just to be clear: the small thumb in the screenshot is of course with src="{{ dataUrl(...) }}"