# Retrieve storage path of image transform instead of URL

Tags: assets, image-transforms

I'm generating base64 encoded strings of very small image transforms to display a blurred version of images while the bigger asset is loading.

I'm trying to get the cached transform path (if it already exists) as I need to extract the actual file content via `file_get_contents()`.

I tried this:

```
$asset->setTransform('rendition8')->getCopyOfFile()
```

But this returns the original asset path, so `setTransform` is ignored.

The workaround I currently use is:

```
$url = $asset->getUrl('rendition8');
$baseUrl = UrlHelper::siteUrl();
$imgUrl = str_replace($baseUrl, '/', $url);
$fullPath = Craft::getAlias('@storage') . $imgUrl;
```

Which is not great...

Is there any other asset method I'm missing?
Maybe it just doesn't exist because the transformed resource might not be generated yet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There’s a discussion on that question, here at [Stackexchange](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/37610/twig-dataurl-function-for-resized-images/40655?noredirect=1#comment48561_40655). There I wrote:

It’s not possible to get a dataUrl from a resized asset at this time, not even in Craft 4.

There’s already an issue for that: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/discussions/11388.

In an older, closed issue, the reason is explained: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/10108.

It is said to be possible with the [Imager X plugin.](https://plugins.craftcms.com/imager-x) And there is a dedicated [Blur Hash Plugin](https://plugins.craftcms.com/blur-hash).

However: We are discussing and testing it currently. Best will be to read the discussion.